# How to solve this Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.CardView

Tags: android, android-layout

I have one card view in adapter when i was running this app it gives me an error and it crashes in some devices with with target version above 27.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'android {
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.umesh"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}}dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.1'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'}
```

and this is my xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/lv_tv"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/ivl_cvItemParent"
        style="@style/example.CardView"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        app:cardElevation="4dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="@drawable/white_bg_selector"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:baselineAligned="false">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:id="@+id/tv_radiostatus"
                    />
            </RelativeLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <TextView
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:text="" />
                <TextView
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:id="@+id/tv_streamername"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:text="" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

i have tried all rebuild and clean project still it crashes when application open any solution will help.thanks

this is my logcat:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                 Process: com.example.umesh, PID: 32004
                                                                 android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
                                                                     at com.example.umesh.All_InfoFragment.RadioListAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(RadioListAdapter.java:38)
                                                                     at com.example.umesh.All_InfoFragment.RadioListAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(RadioListAdapter.java:25)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6685)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5869)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5752)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5748)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2232)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1559)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1519)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:614)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3812)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3529)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4082)
                                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16751)
                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5458)
                                                                     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1079)
                                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16751)
                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5458)
                                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
                                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
                                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16751)
                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5458)
                                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
                                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
                                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
                                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16751)
                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5458)
                                                                     at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.layoutChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:132)
                                                                     at android.support.design.widget.ViewOffsetBehavior.onLayoutChild(ViewOffsetBehavior.java:42)
                                                                     at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onLayoutChild(AppBarLayout.java:1361)
                                                                     at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:894)
                                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16751)
                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5458)
                                                                     at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:1171)
                                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16751)
                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5458)
                                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
                                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
                                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16751)
                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5458)
                                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
                                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
                                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
                                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16751)
                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5458)
                                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
                                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
                                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16751)
                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5458)
                                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
                                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
                                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
                                                                    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:167
```

this is my style for card view:

```
<style name="example" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light" />

<style name="example.CardView">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/white_bg_selector</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">@dimen/cardViewMargin</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">@dimen/cardViewMargin</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginRight">@dimen/cardViewMargin</item>
    <item name="cardElevation">@dimen/cardElevation</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Post your logcat.

Comment: @AnandJain please see logcat added.

Comment: What do you have in `style="@style/tsrnSports.CardView"`? Post your style

Comment: Post your cardview style code

Comment: @VishvaDave style added please check thanks .

Comment: @iDemigod style added.

Comment: @umeshvashisth test case : change android:background to cardBackgroundColor

Comment: I think the problem is here `<style name="tsrnSports" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light" />`, your should extend widget style (probably `CardView.Light`), not the whole Theme.

Comment: @VishvaDave ther is no sach key found CardBackgroundColor .but i have tried colorbackground and its not working.still crash

Comment: @iDemigod <style name="tsrnSports" parent="CardView.Light" /> tested still got crash

Comment: @umeshvashisth, have you tried this without style at all? (CardView without style, just attributes from layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try :**

```
<style name="mycardview" parent="CardView">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/white_bg_selector</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">@dimen/cardViewMargin</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">@dimen/cardViewMargin</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginRight">@dimen/cardViewMargin</item>
    <item name="cardElevation">@dimen/cardElevation</item>
</style>
```

Comment: this code will be after previous styles i.e after </style>.. it will not be inside any style.. also remove `<style name="tsrnSports" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light" />`

Comment: yes i got that and tried with as u said ...but still not working.///

Comment: after changing style clean rebuild and then run the app

Comment: @umeshvashisth can you post white_bg_selector in question as without that it is working for me

Comment: yo thanks buddy yes you are right white_bg_selector was the problem.

Comment: @umeshvashisth Happy to help :) happy coding :)